# Rails where to place your Activemodel::validators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activemodel

This is a two part question.

Part one if my Model that i am writing the validations for is inhering from `ActiveRecord::Base` do i need to `include ActiveModel::Validations` within that class?? the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validator.html) for rails doesnt say but here in [yehudakatz](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/) blog seems to hint that?

part two is where would be the best place to put these validator files? under helpers or as a new model or in lib?

my current validator looks like this

```
class GenderValidator < ActiveModel::validator
  def validate(record)
    cred = /(\d{6})(\d{4})(\d{1})(\d{2})/.match(record.id_number.to_s) #breaks up the id into the relevent sections namely birthdate, gender, nationality, validator.
    unless cred[0][/\d{13}/] #checks to see if the id is a valid length of numbers if it isnt then skip the validation of gender
      return true
    else
      birthdate = cred[1] #returns a 6 digit string 'yymmdd'
      parsed_gender = cred[2] #returns a 4 digit string '0001-4999:female 5000-9999:male'
      nationality = cred[3] # should return either a 1 or a 0 1 if the person is foreign or 0 if the person is southafrican

      validate_gender(parsed_gender, record)
    end
  end

  private
  def validate_gender(parsed_gender, record)
    calculate_gender = (parsed_gender <= 4999 ? :female : :male)
      unless employee.gender == calculate_gender
        employee.errors[:gender] << "Your id indicates you have entered the wrong gender"
      end
  end
end
```

an valid id number of each person is optional, but if they do specify it it should check to see if the gender is correct.

if i keep it in the same model the employees model then i get this error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Employee::GenderValidator):
app/models/employee.rb:25:in `<class:Employee>'
app/models/employee.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
lib/role_requirement_system.rb:19:in `inherited'
app/controllers/employees_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
librato-rails (0.8.1) lib/librato/rack/middleware.rb:12:in `call'
```

so i take it they cant be in the same file. what is the best practice for validations? i watched all the rails casts and i have read a few blogs and i am quite new still.

EDIT

in my model i include this class like

```
include ActiveModel::Validations
```

and my validations look like this

```
validates_presence_of :name, :position, :gender
validate :instance_validations, :on => :create

def instance_validations
  validates_with GenderValidator    
end
```

just incase you wanted to see that too
thanks ahead!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need include ActiveModel::Validations

My preference to to keep the validation objects in the model folder.

So for model Gender you have a file gender.rb

For the validator GenderValidator you have the file gender_validator.rb

So both files site together in the model folder.

Here is a validator for my Newsletter model

```
class NewsletterValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
      if record.send_test_email
        if test_email_address.blank?
          record.errors[:test_email_address] << "Test email address is blank"
        end
        if record.send_email_to_subscribers
          record.errors[:send_test_email] << "You cannot send a test and send to subscribers at the same time"
        end
      end

  end
end
```

In my Newsletter model I simply have

```
  validates_with NewsletterValidator
```

You have a spelling  mistake in your example

You have

```
class GenderValidator < ActiveModel::validator
```

It should be

```
class GenderValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
```

Note the capital V